# axum-typed-routing Aditional Route Params

Tags: rust-axum, axum, axum-login

I implemented Axum login following one of the example in their repo.
Unfortunately, I run into this problem.
Can does anyone know whar

At the end, I probably will use axum_session_auth, but did not find the time to test this on. I guess I will have the same problem at the end.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `fn(axum::extract::Path<(u32,)>, axum::extract::Query<__QueryParams__>, axum::extract::State<AppState>, extractors::Json<u32>, axum_login::AuthSession<users::Backend>) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = std::string::String> {__inner__function__}: OperationHandler<_, _>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:120:1
    |
120 | / #[api_route(GET "/item/:id?amount&offset&test" with AppState {
121 | |     summary: "Get an item",
122 | |     description: "Get an item by id",
123 | |     id: "get-item",
...   |
127 | |     responses: { 200: String },
128 | | })]
    | |___^ the trait `OperationHandler<_, _>` is not implemented for fn item `fn(axum::extract::Path<(u32,)>, axum::extract::Query<__QueryParams__>, axum::extract::State<AppState>, extractors::Json<u32>, axum_login::AuthSession<users::Backend>) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = std::string::String> {__inner__function__}`
    |
note: required by a bound in `get_with`
   --> /Users/gradlon/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/aide-0.13.2/src/axum/routing.rs:345:1
    |
345 | method_router_top_level!(get, get_with);
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------^
    | |                             |
    | |                             required by a bound in this function
    | required by this bound in `get_with`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `api_route` which comes from the expansion of the macro `method_router_top_level` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

This is the code used:

```
#[allow(unused_variables)]
#[api_route(GET "/item/:id?amount&offset&test" with AppState {
    summary: "Get an item",
    description: "Get an item by id",
    id: "get-item",
    tags: ["items"],
    hidden: false
    security: { "auth_session": ["read:items"] },
    responses: { 200: String },
})]
async fn item_handler(
    id: u32,
    amount: Option<u32>,
    offset: Option<u32>,
    test: Option<u32>,
    State(state): State<AppState>,
    Json(json): Json<u32>,
    auth_session: AuthSession,
) -> String {
    "let user = User".to_string()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the `OperationHandler` not being implemented for your `AuthSession`. You can solve this by using [`NoApi`](https://docs.rs/aide/latest/aide/struct.NoApi.html) to wrap `AuthSesstion` in order to create an empty default documentation.

Your code should look something like this:

```
use aide::NoApi;

#[allow(unused_variables)]
#[api_route(GET "/item/:id?amount&offset&test" with AppState {
    summary: "Get an item",
    description: "Get an item by id",
    id: "get-item",
    tags: ["items"],
    hidden: false
    security: { "auth_session": ["read:items"] },
    responses: { 200: String },
})]

type AuthSessionNoApi = NoApi(AuthSession);

async fn item_handler(
    id: u32,
    amount: Option<u32>,
    offset: Option<u32>,
    test: Option<u32>,
    state): State<AppState>,
    Json(json): Json<u32>,
    auth_session: AuthSessionNoApi,
) -> String {
    "let user = User".to_string()
}
```

For more background information check: https://github.com/tamasfe/aide/issues/63